# Magento "getCategories()" returns empty array

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to list all of the categories for site by using the following code:

```
public function showcategoriesAction()
{
    var_dump($this->getCategories());
}
```

However, it is returning empty array. I have several sites that are using the above code and they are returning category list without any problem. For this two particular site I cannot seem to get it. They have categories in their system and they are visible. Not sure what is wrong or how I can fix it.

Additionally, in other sites under `System > Configuration` there is `Catalog`, but for the one that are not working it is `System > Configuration > Catalogue`. I'm not sure there is a difference between them tho.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get all categories,

```
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addIsActiveFilter();
```